DataNotMatchException: <DataNotMatchException: (code=1, message=The Input data type is inconsistent
image is existing schema from zilliz, message.txt is error log, sample_input.txt is sample input text.
sample input langchain document object
[Document(metadata={'id_pk': {'array': [288204]}, 'url': {'array': ['example.com']}, 'url_id': 'example.com', 'categories': {'array': ['culture', 'music']}, 'locations': {'array': ['france', 'brooklyn', 'new york', 'manhattan', 'socceroof', 'sunset park', 'united states']}, 'country': {'array': ['united states']}, 'province': {'array': ['new york']}, 'city': {'array': ['new york', 'brooklyn']}, 'poi': {'array': ['socceroof', 'sunset park', 'manhattan']}, 'published_year': 2024, 'content_type': {'array': ['posts']}, 'source': {}}, page_content="My content to be added")]

